# Does a jQuery Slider with Ken Burns Effect Setting Per Image Exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

There are several options as for a jquery based ken burns slider, such as:

https://github.com/toymakerlabs/kenburns
and
http://kthornbloom.com/smoothslides/

However, I can't seem to find one that allows to set options per image. The auto/random thing is nice, but that doesn't work for every image.

I would love to see something that would allow to set the effects in the markup. Maybe something like:

```
<ul class="kbslider">
    <li class="left-right fade"><img></li>
    <li class="right-left fade"><img></li>
    <li class="top-bottom fade"><img></li>
    <li class="bottomleft-centerright fade"><img></li>
    <li class="still nofade"><img></li>
    <li class="center-zoomin"><img></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know of a jquery solution with such per image options or something along that line?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with coding related questions. So you might ask your question on Stackoverflow's new sister site that deals with software recommendations.  To get a good answer, make sure your question is well stated and detailed: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information. Good luck with your project!